# Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter '_questionBank'

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz26f.png)

Can you help me please?

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named '_questionBank'.

Comment: You don't have fields with those names. What did you expect? They aren't defined in that class

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image